# Can't make keyword delimiters work in Assets Files tag

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

Using P&T Assets, assuming I have two files in my Assets folder (folder_id="2"), one having the keyword "tinman" associated with it, the other with "scarecrow", shouldn't this template code return them both?:

```
              <ul>
                {exp:assets:files folder_id="2" keywords="tinman|scarecrow"}
                  <li>
                      <a href="{url}">
                        {title}
                      </a> 
                  </li>
                {/exp:assets:files}
              </ul>
```

It doesn't seem to work for me. The keyword parameter only accepts one term and won't respect the "|" delimiter.

Comment: According to the docs that should work. Have you got the latest version? Is this on EE 2.8? if 2.8 there could be new bugs interfering.

Comment: EE 2.7.3. Assets 2.2.2, not 2.2.4. I'll try updating.

Comment: Updated Assets. Still nothing.